# Android studio cannot install - Failed to fetch addons_list-2.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, osx-yosemite

Trying to install Android Studio on OSX 10.0 Yosemite & it gets stuck 'Downloading Components' from Wizard

```
Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml,
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, 
  reason: File not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'.android' folder in your home directory is only changeable by root.

Run this in terminal:

`sudo chmod a+rwx ~/.android && sudo chmod a+rwx ~/.android/*`